# Replacing components in a Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

We have a Webpack bundle exposing React components. The exposed components contain nested components from the same bundle.
We want to allow users to replace components with their own specific version.

For example, the following component structure;

```
class A extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <B/>
        );
    }
}

const C = require('./C');

class B extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <C/>
        );
    }
}
```

from which the top-level component A is exposed in the Webpack bundle:

```
const A = bundle.components.A;
```

Our server-side web framework relies on the exposed bundle interface to invoke the React components.

From this structure, an example use-case would be to replace the nested component C from component A.

Current options that we see for this are;

- add a method to the class B (and A) to replace component C
- create a registration mechanism, e.g. by using the filename or logical name of C, and a generic method to the bundle to replace a component. For example: `bundle.component.replace('./C', './custom-C');`
- ...

What would be the best way, i.e. common practice, to replace a (nested) React component in a Webpack bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Joost, I've got the same problem and the way that I'm been handling this is creating an Block component which decides what component should take place.

This is a working project importing webpack bundles and deciding which one should take place. If they are defined in the template scope I switch the render method.

https://github.com/wallynm/react-template-system

Answer (score 0):

In the end we chose to use render-props, HOCs, and adding some replace functions for specific components.

Comment: [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.